# Use `ListBox` from `@headlessui/react` with Mobx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

## Before using ListBox:

### store/index.ts

```
import { action, makeObservable, observable } from 'mobx'
import type { IFrameItStore, TrafficSignal } from '@/types/index'

export class FrameItStore implements IFrameItStore {
    trafficSignal: TrafficSignal = {
        shape: 'circle',
    }

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            trafficSignal: observable,
            updateTrafficSignal: action.bound,
        })
    }

    updateTrafficSignal({ shape }: TrafficSignal) {
        if (shape) this.trafficSignal.shape = shape
    }
}
```

### Shape.tsx

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import * as React from 'react'

import { useFrameItStore } from '@/store/index'
import type { TrafficSignalShape } from '@/types/index'

export const Shape = observer(() => {
    const frameItStore = useFrameItStore()
    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor="shape" className="mb-1 text-sm font-medium text-blue-gray-500">
                Shape
            </label>
            <select
                id="shape"
                className="block w-full px-3 py-2 mb-2 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm text-blue-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                value={frameItStore.trafficSignal.shape}
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
                    const shape = e.target.value as TrafficSignalShape
                    frameItStore.updateTrafficSignal({ shape })
                }}
            >
                <option value="circle">Circle</option>
                <option value="square">Square</option>
            </select>
        </>
    )
})
```

### App.tsx

```
<Shape />
```

## After using ListBox:

### Select.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import clsx from 'clsx'

import { Selector, Check } from '@/components/icons/index'

type Option = {
    id: string
    name: string
    img: string
}

interface IProps {
    label?: string
    options: Array<Option>
}

export const Select = ({ label, options }: IProps) => {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState<Option>(options[0])

    return (
        <Listbox value={selectedOption} onChange={setSelectedOption}>
            {({ open }) => (
                <>
                    <Listbox.Label className="mb-1 text-sm font-medium text-blue-gray-500">
                        {label}
                    </Listbox.Label>

                    <div className="relative mt-1">
                        <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                            <span className="flex items-center">
                                <img
                                    src={selectedOption.img}
                                    alt={selectedOption.name}
                                    className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 rounded-full"
                                />
                                <span className="block ml-3 truncate">{selectedOption.name}</span>
                            </span>
                            <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 ml-3 pointer-events-none">
                                <Selector />
                            </span>
                        </Listbox.Button>

                        <div className="absolute w-full mt-1 bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg">
                            <Transition
                                show={open}
                                leave="transition duration-100 ease-in"
                                leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                                leaveTo="opacity-0"
                            >
                                <Listbox.Options
                                    static
                                    className="py-1 overflow-auto text-base rounded-md max-h-56 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
                                >
                                    {options.map((option) => (
                                        <Listbox.Option as={React.Fragment} key={option.id} value={option}>
                                            {({ active, selected }) => (
                                                <li
                                                    className={clsx('relative py-2 pl-3 cursor-default select-none pr-9', {
                                                        'text-white bg-indigo-600': active,
                                                        'text-gray-900': !active,
                                                    })}
                                                >
                                                    <div className="flex items-center">
                                                        <img
                                                            src={option.img}
                                                            alt={option.name}
                                                            className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 rounded-full"
                                                        />
                                                        <span
                                                            className={clsx('ml-3 block truncate', {
                                                                'font-semibold': selected,
                                                                'font-normal': !selected,
                                                            })}
                                                        >
                                                            {option.name}
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    {selected && (
                                                        <span
                                                            className={clsx('absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4', {
                                                                'text-white': active,
                                                                'text-indigo-600': !active,
                                                            })}
                                                        >
                                                            <Check />
                                                        </span>
                                                    )}
                                                </li>
                                            )}
                                        </Listbox.Option>
                                    ))}
                                </Listbox.Options>
                            </Transition>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </Listbox>
    )
}
```

## App.tsx

```
const shapes = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Circle',
        img:
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Square',
        img:
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
    },
]

<Select label="Shape" options={shapes} />
```

How do I convert the **After** part to use MobX like the **Before** part?

I tried passing `value` & `onChange` as it is in the **Before** part to **Select** like:

### App.tsx

```
<Select
  label="Shape"
  options={shapes}
  value={frameItStore.trafficSignal.shape}
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const shape = e.target.value as TrafficSignalShape
    frameItStore.updateTrafficSignal({ shape })
  }}
/>
```

### Select.tsx

```
interface IProps {
    label?: string
    value: any
    onChange: (value: any) => void
    options: Array<Option>
}

export const Select = ({ label, options, value, onChange }: IProps) => {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState<Option>(options[0])

    return (
        <Listbox value={value} onChange={onChange}>
        .
        .
        .
        </Listbox>
    )
}
```

But it doesn't select anything & I don't know what to do of `selectedOption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I solved it. Removed the local hook state & just used the MobX state. Also, had 1 minor issue. I was setting the value as uppercase in the store when the store originally had lowercase values. The uppercase values were only for display in the UI.

Here's the modified code that works:

## App.tsx

```
<Select
  label="Shape"
  options={shapes}
  value={shapes.filter({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === frameItStore.trafficSignal.shape)[0]}
  onChange={(value) => {
    const shape = value.toLowerCase() as TrafficSignalShape
    frameItStore.updateTrafficSignal({ shape })
  }}
/>
```

## Select.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import clsx from 'clsx'

import { Selector, Check } from '@/components/icons/index'

type Option = {
    id: string
    name: string
    img: string
}

interface IProps {
    label?: string
    value: Option
    onChange: (name: string) => void
    options: Array<Option>
}

export const Select = ({ label, options, value, onChange }: IProps) => {
    return (
        <Listbox
            value={value}
            onChange={(value: Option) => {
                onChange(value.name)
            }}
        >
            {({ open }) => (
                <>
                    <Listbox.Label className="mb-1 text-sm font-medium text-blue-gray-500">
                        {label}
                    </Listbox.Label>

                    <div className="relative mt-1">
                        <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                            <span className="flex items-center">
                                <img
                                    src={value.img}
                                    alt={value.name}
                                    className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 rounded-full"
                                />
                                <span className="block ml-3 truncate">{value.name}</span>
                            </span>
                            <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 ml-3 pointer-events-none">
                                <Selector />
                            </span>
                        </Listbox.Button>

                        <div className="absolute z-10 w-full mt-1 bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg">
                            <Transition
                                show={open}
                                leave="transition duration-100 ease-in"
                                leaveFrom="transform opacity-100"
                                leaveTo="transform opacity-0"
                            >
                                <Listbox.Options
                                    static
                                    className="py-1 overflow-auto text-base rounded-md max-h-56 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
                                >
                                    {options.map((option) => {
                                        return (
                                            <Listbox.Option as={React.Fragment} key={option.id} value={option}>
                                                {({ active, selected }) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <li
                                                            className={clsx(
                                                                'relative py-2 pl-3 cursor-default select-none pr-9',
                                                                {
                                                                    'text-white bg-indigo-600': active,
                                                                    'text-gray-900': !active,
                                                                }
                                                            )}
                                                        >
                                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                                <img
                                                                    src={option.img}
                                                                    alt={option.name}
                                                                    className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 rounded-full"
                                                                />
                                                                <span
                                                                    className={clsx('ml-3 block truncate', {
                                                                        'font-semibold': selected,
                                                                        'font-normal': !selected,
                                                                    })}
                                                                >
                                                                    {option.name}
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            {selected && (
                                                                <span
                                                                    className={clsx(
                                                                        'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4',
                                                                        {
                                                                            'text-white': active,
                                                                            'text-indigo-600': !active,
                                                                        }
                                                                    )}
                                                                >
                                                                    <Check />
                                                                </span>
                                                            )}
                                                        </li>
                                                    )
                                                }}
                                            </Listbox.Option>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </Listbox.Options>
                            </Transition>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </Listbox>
    )
}
```